# Can outdated programming software be harmful?

Tags: java

I recently bought a book called "Killer Game Programming in Java" It's about 5 years old now and the programs run best with Java2SE and Java 2SE 1.4. Since these versions are old and not updated, could using these software versions be harmful. The link below says yes but I wanted a second opinion before I try to install. Also, I'm running on a Mac. If all else fails I'm gonna try to email the author.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#7501-j2sdk-1.4.2-oth-JPR

Comment: I suspect the author wrote something like "works best with Java2SE 1.4", but meant "does not work with versions prior to 1.4".  In that case, just install the latest version and proceed.

Comment: Your close. He said his code is designed to compile and run in J2SE 5.0 and J2Se 1.4 as to avoid using new language features and API introduced in J2SE 5.0. The main reason is so that it is backwards compatible with older versions. BUT if a few more people take your side I'm just gonna go ahead and install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a game in Java 1.4. This book you said, will help you to understant Java but you don't have to create the final game in 1.4. Take ideas from this book and update them accordingly to the newest version of Java.